# How do you properly call a JS function within HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm relatively new to the wonders of Javascript and cannot make a breakthrough on this issue. I've done some troubleshooting, and I'm pretty sure my JS file is being loaded, but I can't get anything within it to execute - JS code works fine inline within  HTML.

Relevant code:

```js
function mobileNavBar() {
  var x = document.getElementById("nav-bar-ul");
  if (x.className === "nav-bar-links") {
    x.className += "responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "nav-bar-links";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Testing</title>
  <script src="myScripts.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/lye7pws.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-template.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <nav id="nav-bar">
    <a href="#" class="logo-link">
      <div class="logo" id="firstName">
        <h1>name</h1>
      </div>
      <ul id="logo-list">
        <li>
          <div class="door"></div>
          <div class="knob"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="logo" id="lastName">
            <h1>name</h1>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </a>
    <ul class="nav-bar-links" id="nav-bar-ul">
      <li><a class="underline" href="#">Play</a></li>
      <li><a class="underline active-underline" href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a class="underline" href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="nav-bar-icon" onclick="mobileNavBar()">
      <img src="images/menu-icon.svg" width="50px" height="50px">
    </a>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's some things that I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    <!-- same script code above -->
}
```

---

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    <!-- same script code above -->
}
```

Worst comes to worst, I can keep the code inline - but I'd rather do things properly and learn proper techniques. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you're trying to load that js file before the page is built. Try adding putting that script tag before the `</body`> tag.

Comment: A short answer: you shouldn't call JS from HTML at all. Use `addEventListener` to attach the events, (or jQuery's event model, if you're using jQuery). The issue in your code is, that inline listeners need a global function to refer, they can't see inside the callback of `document.ready()` or `window.addEventListener`.

Comment: I've tried moving the script tag like you've mentioned @justDan, but that doesn't make it work :(

Comment: @Teemu, do you mind elaborating on how to structure the code in the way of using addEventListener ?

Comment: If you really have to use inline listeners, then just put the linking script tag to the end of the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

1) You say you believe your javascript file loads correctly.  According to your script tag in html it believes that the javascript file is sitting right next to your html file in the directory (you might have this already, but just a double check).

2) When you are doing "x.className += "responsive"" you are appending the name right after the current class text, so it would be: "nav-bar-linksresponsive" which is not a class.  I think what you are going for is x.classList.add("responsive").

3) You are also missing the opening "HTML" tag at the top of the document.  Not sure if this is how it actually is or if you just pasted it this way in the example.

I copied the above code into a test.html file and test.js file, and I did see the .js function being triggered on the link press, but just saw the class being created incorrectly like I mentioned in #2.

Comment: Thanks @Ben Krueger ! 

1) This is correct, but it's always worth mentioning 
2) This was my issue - the code I had works, it's actually straight from w3schools, I just forgot a space before responsive

    x.classname += " responsive";

Your method of classList.add might be a better way of doing this though, so I'll play with getting that to work.